# Is it possible to change the date format?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I use a PostgreSQL and ORM Sequelize database. And I want to change the date format from `YYYY-MM-DD` to `DD.MM.YYYY`. Is it possible to do this?

```
    ...
    date_work: {
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
        required: true  
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, you can do in code and then assign to "date_work" key

Comment: You can use momentjs for all date features. https://momentjs.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) like

```
sequelize.define('TableName', {
  DateTime: {
    type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    get: function() {
       return moment(this.getDataValue('DateTime')).format('DD.MM.YYYY')
    }
  }
}
```